# Making form mailer compatible with PHP 5.4

Tags: php

The php on my server has been upgraded to 5.4 & and my contact form mailer no longer works. 
Kindly see the following code:

Here is my HTML

```
<form id="contact" action="contact.php"  method="post" name="contact">
    <fieldset id="personal">
        <label for="name">Name :</label>
        <input name="a_name" type="text" />
        <br />                  
        <label for="email">Email : </label>
        <input name="a_email" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and PHP

```
<?php
     import_request_variables("gP");

     $msgc .= "Name:\t$name\n";
     $msgc .= "Email:\t$email\n";

    mail('abc@gmail.com','Message from Website',$msgc,$mheaderc);

?>
```

Please let me know how to get this working in PHP5.4
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: In this case it was easy to spot the problem. However, next time you ask a question, you might want to define 'no longer works'. For instance by providing the error message, or by explaining how the actual output differs from what you expected. That helps people who are trying to help you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The PHP function [`import_request_variables()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.import-request-variables.php) is removed in PHP 5.4, as you can read in the documentation:

> **Warning** This function has been *DEPRECATED* as of PHP 5.3.0 and *REMOVED* as of
>   PHP 5.4.0.

Instead, you should use [`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

So, replace

```
import_request_variables("gP");
```

with

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

I would also recommend to check that the user input is valid (for instance that the provided email address is actually a valid email address) and does not contain malicious code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is using [`import_request_variables()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.import-request-variables.php) that was removed in 5.4, but which is unsafe anyway, so you should not use it. Use `$_POST[]` and `$_GET[]` instead.

So instead of:

```
import_request_variables("gP');
```

Write:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: I usually don't downvote other people's answers. But not only did you copy most of my answer, you actually made some typo's in the process, so your answer will not work. That's why I downvoted you.

Comment: @Nic, I saw the typos and corrected them. On the point of copying your answer, that is simply not true. You are not the only one capable of using google. I only saw your answer after I completed my own and most certainly did not copy anything from it.

Comment: In that case, sorry for accusing you of that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 $msgc .= "Name:\t$name\n";
 $msgc .= "Email:\t$email\n";
```

to

```
 $msgc = "Name:\t$name\n";
 $msgc .= "Email:\t$email\n";
```

Also, where did you define `$mheaderc`, `$name` and `$email`?